Elegant higher order+dimension Leibniz rule for polyhedra
Let $ y \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $. For $ 1 \leq j \leq m $ let
$$
H_j = \{ x : u_j x + a_j y \geq 0 \}
$$
be $ n-1 $-dimensional affine half-spaces and $ \partial H_j $ their boundary. Consider for $ J \subseteq \{1, \dots, m\} $ the $ |J| $-dimensional subspaces
$$
U_J = \bigcap_{j \in J} u_j^\perp
$$
as well as the $ |J| $-dimensional polyhedra
$$
P_J = \left( \bigcap_{j \in J} \partial H_j \right) \cap \left( \bigcap_{i \notin J} H_i \right).
$$
I am looking for an elegant higher-order version of the Leibniz integral rule in this setting:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^p}{\mathrm{d} y^p} \int_{P_J} F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|}(x) = \dots 
$$
I feel like there ought to be a somewhat clean formulation. What I could find so far is the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} y} \int_{P_J} F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|}(x) &= \int_{P_J} \left( \partial_y + \sum_{j \in J} a_j u_j \cdot \nabla_x \right) F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|}(x) \\
    &\quad + \sum_{i \notin J} \left| \pi_{U_J} u_i \right| a_i \int_{P_{J \cup \{i\}}} F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|+1}(x)
\end{align*}
$$
Maybe I should explain a bit. Here $\mathcal{H}^k$ ist he $k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. The term with $\sum_{j \in J} a_j u_j \cdot \nabla_x$ measures the change due to the shift of the whole polyhedron with the shift of the affine subspace $\bigcap_{j \in J} \partial H_j$. The term with $\left| \pi_{U_J} u_i \right| a_i$ measures the change due to the shift of the $i$-th boundary section of the polyhedron projected to the current subspace of consideration $U_J$.
We could now iterate this:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} y^2} \int_{P_J} F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|}(x) &= \int_{P_J} \left( \partial_y + \sum_{j \in J} a_j u_j \cdot \nabla_x \right)^2 F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|}(x) \\
    &\quad + \sum_{i \notin J} \left| \pi_{U_J} u_i \right| a_i \int_{P_{J \cup \{i\}}} \left( \partial_y + \sum_{j \in J} a_j u_j \cdot \nabla_x \right) F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|+1}(x) \\
    &\quad + \sum_{i \notin J} \left| \pi_{U_J} u_i \right| a_i \int_{P_{J \cup \{i\}}} \left( \partial_y + \sum_{j \in J \cup \{i\}} a_j u_j \cdot \nabla_x \right) F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|+1}(x) \\
    &\quad + \sum_{i \notin J} \left| \pi_{U_J} u_i \right| a_i \sum_{k \notin J \cup \{i\}} \left| \pi_{U_{J \cup \{i\}}} u_k \right| a_k \int_{P_{J \cup \{i, k\}}} F(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^{|J|+2}(x)
\end{align*}
$$
But this doesn't really come out to something which I find sufficiently clean. I will update/answer the question if I find a nice formulation. I suppose there is a way to write this with iterative applications of a general version of Stokes' theorem, but I'm struggling with what the integrand would be on the "higher boundaries" $\partial \dots \partial P$.
Thanks!
